# Differences of Servlet and Classic ASP in handling Requests

Tags: asp-classic

I have no knowledge in Classic ASP, and I'm tasked to solve XSS and XSRF vulnerabilities of the Classic ASP web application. I need to know the following:

1. How do I submit a request value to
   the next page, if I'm using a
   Response.Redirect("someurl")? I'm not allowed to use GET, only POST.
2. Does Response Redirect behave like RequestDispatcher sendRedirect?
3. How do I do a forward instead of redirect in classic ASP?
4. How do I set a request attribute in classic ASP without using a form?

Comment: this has nothing to do with servlets whatsoever. And "x vs. y" isn't appropriate at all as a title.

Comment: Basic topic question is very broad.

Answer (score 1):

Response.Redirect in classic asp sends a HTTP 302 Object Moved status code to the client. furthermore it sends the "new" location. so the client will send a new request to the "new" location.

you could use server xmlhttp to do a post request on the server side..

[Response.Redirect Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524309%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)

[How To Submit Form Data by Using XMLHTTP or ServerXMLHTTP Object](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/290591/en-us)

Answer (score 1):

> How do I do a forward instead of redirect in classic ASP?

I guess you mean pass the existing form data to different page? For this use `Server.Transfer` method.

> How do I set a request attribute in classic ASP without using a form?

You can't it's Read Only. If you mean how it's possible to imitate Posting form data without actual form, it's possible using basic AJAX and you must assume every visitor can do it, meaning you **can't** trust `Request.Form` values. They can easily be spoofed.

Answer (score 0):

In answer to part 1, 4

To send a value without using a form use

response.redirect("target_page.asp?MyParam=Something")

to retrieve a value in the target_page from a named parameter sent by the GET method, use

MyVariable = Request.QueryString("MyParam")

Comment: this is correct, however, you did not answer the question, it's stated that I'm not allowed to use GET

Comment: You did not read my answer.  I was only responding to parts 1 and 4